# How to calculate a quadratic equation in Python

Tags: python, math

I want to do some simple calculation with variables.
But this `x` is not variable on often seen in programs, but `x = unknown` in math formula.

I want calculate this

`(x-1)^2 =`

and get

`x^2 - 4x + 4`

is it possible??

I am familiar with some program language, but its first time to use math purpose.

Comment: It seems you want to do symbolic math in python. If that's the case [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) is as far as I know the best solution for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Chen Guevara's comment here is a tiny snippet of [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html)-using code to illustrate.

```py
from sympy import symbols, expand

x = symbols('x')
expr = (x-1)**2
print(expr)
expr2 = expand(expr)
print(expr2)
```

This produces the output:

```
(x - 1)**2
x**2 - 2*x + 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 8

quadratic = ((x ** 2) - (4 * x)) + 4
print(quadratic)
```

returns 36. is this what youre looking for?